# Is it possible to position background-attachment: fixed relatively to div not viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make a `background-attachment:fixed;` for `div` which positioned by `div` position not with viewport? If not, maybe there are some other alternatives?

**CSS**

```
.zest-ghost {
        width: 302px;
        height: 222px;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        background-image: url(../images/logo-ghost.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

**HTML**
`<div class="zest-ghost"></div>`

> This code makes image `fixed` relatively to viewport and not with `div`. I
>   need same effect but with the possibility to move the image left or
>   right. An image should have its original width and height

Comment: Show us what you have tried with?

Comment: Theres not mutch to show.. May I ask why I'm getting negatives? .. :)

Comment: I believe you were down voted, because down voters did not recognize you were talking about the `background-attachment` property, because you just asked for something to be `fixed`. I think, that you do not want to have the background inside the div moving, which isn't so trivial.

Comment: I'm guessing you got downvoted because your original question lacked quality.

Comment: @Abbr what do you mean by that?

Comment: Have a look at my most recent edit. It relationally moves the background image while having an offset by its own.

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/V8WqE/4/

Comment: @ Giedidius, can you please xplain exactly what you mean, do you have an example you have seen somewhere online? Do you want a div which displays a fixed pic on the left, while on the right half there is a scrolling background?

Comment: A bit hardcore and limiting, but you could use an iframe for your div

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the page (body) down and have the background of the div stay in place. So in short this would be the basics for a [parallax design](https://eu.ixquick.com/do/search?q=parallax+design&lui=english)? Of cause it will not move slower than the scrolling speed, but that can be done with javascript. This CSS should be the starting point in order to make the page as usable as possible without javascript.

Then I think you want something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <style>
      html,body
      { height:100%; }

      body
      {
        background-position:0px 0px;
        background-attachment: fixed;
      }

      .test
      {
        height:4em;
        background:url('150x150.jpg');
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position:5px 0px;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      div.space
      {
        height:70%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="space">a</div>

    <div class="test">
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hhdf6639/5

Comment: Thant's not what I need. Basically what I need is to move the background image to left, but it should have `background-attachment: fixed` effect and would fit div size.

Comment: then add `background-size:cover` to it as I have already done in the jsfiddle link. What do you mean by 'left'? Do you have a left scrolling page?

Comment: you could at least vote me up, if this comes closer to what you want to do and which I haven't understood completely yet :/

Answer (score 0):

We can use `background-position` property for this. Instead of using `center`, you can use pixels to actually move the image within a div.

```
.zest-ghost {
        width: 302px;
        height: 222px;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        background-image: url(../images/logo-ghost.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 50% 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

The above will adjust the x-axis cropped content to 50% and moves the image down vertically by `20px`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you

```
     .zest-ghost{
            background-image: url('../images/zest-logo-ghost.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/jdmitz/V8WqE/

Comment: It's fixed for viewport not for div. I need same effect with a possibility to move the image left or right.

Comment: And what exactly is different here from the OPs code? The `100%` `height`/`width`? How does it solve the problem?